# sqlalchemy argument for postgresql serial primary key in pyramid framework

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I have found related questions but can't adapt them to my situation. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15439514/sqlalchemy-and-auto-increments-with-postgresql) and the postgresql docs [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sequences-serial).

I'm using sqlalchemy to interact with a postgresql db in a pyramid (python) framework (OS Ubuntu).

My schema is described in a `models.py` file.

I'm trying to insert the record in my `views.py`:

```
cam_event = Event(key,'fileprefix',now,'CAM',outfile,
                  'new fake project','new fake memo')
```

where I would like to submit a null, none, or leave the position empty ('key' position in the line above) in my add command so that posgresql will fill it in.  When I do any of those  I get a "Programming Error" from one of the pyramid backend bits.

Comment: can your post your solution as an Answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.  I had tried not specifying the primary_key column in my object creation, but that didn't work with an existing database with non-sequential numbers already in the table from earlier work.  I dropped the table and let sqlalchemy create it fresh and never provided values for the primary_key field, just specified the sequence and let postgresql deal with the numbering.