# Sequence not created while creating table using SqlAchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I tried to create a table with `id` column using sequence but kept failed.

Here is my snippet of code:

```
from sqlalchemy import (TEXT, Boolean, Column, Date, DateTime,
                        ForeignKey, Integer, Sequence, SmallInteger, String,
                        UniqueConstraint)

class group(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'group'

    id = Column(SmallInteger, Sequence('group_id'), primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    sorting = Column(SmallInteger, nullable=False, index=True)
    active = Column(Boolean, nullable=False, index=True, default=True)
```

The table generated like this but no sequence:

```
CREATE TABLE group (
    id SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    title VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    sorting SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    active BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE (title)
)
CREATE INDEX ix_group_sorting ON group (sorting)
CREATE INDEX ix_group_active ON group (active)
```

Therefore, if I try to insert data into the table, the error message shows up:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InternalError: (psycopg2.errors.InternalError_) missing "id" primary key column
```

How can I successfully create a table with column using Sequence?

sqlalchemy version: 1.0.14

python version: 3.6.6

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried something like - `Sequence('group_id', start=1, increment=1)`

Comment: Yes, but it's not working either.

Comment: Please refer  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15439514/sqlalchemy-and-auto-increments-with-postgresql